# How Crashlytics finds exact source of crash

Tags: java, android, exception, crashlytics, crash-log

Using Throwable object, we can get the full stack trace of the crash, and using its class name we can also get the type of exception e.g. `java.lang.NullPointerException`, `java.lang.ArithmeticException` etc.

Following image is taken from the **crashlytics which finds the exact source of crash from the entire crash log and also highlights the same with blue color**. I need to understand how crashlytics finds out the exact lines of code that made the app crash.

[image]

The Next Picture which is after scrolling at the end of crash log is below:

[image]

As you can see in the pics, crashlytics highlighted only two lines in the pics from entire crash log, if I iterate over the `StrackTraceElement`, I get all the lines from the array till the end which is unnecessary.

I want to know the exact lines of crash log which indicates the main reason behind the crash programmatically.

Comment: `Throwable#getStackTrace()`

Comment: @pskink I know it and mentioned it in the question as well, I want to know the exact lines of crash log which indicates the main reason behind the crash programmatically.

Comment: exact lines? like what? class name? file name? method name? line number? its all in `StackTraceElement`

Comment: @pskink the lines which are highlighted in blue in the picture above.

Comment: Than you @pskink I am able to get the first line info i.e. class name, method name, file name and line number, how to get that second line which has file name `LocateMe.java`

Comment: you have the array, right? so iterate over it - just like `for (StackTraceElement traceElement : trace)
                System.out.println("\tat " + traceElement);` for example

Comment: @pskink please check I have updated the question, as you suggested if i iterate over the array, i get all the lines till the end from the crash log above.

Comment: if you want to get the cause of the exception then call `Throwable#getCause()`

Comment: @pskink Using `Throwable#getCause()` and getting its `StackTraceElement` giving same result.

Comment: no, it is not, by calling `getCause()` you are getting the "cause" `Throwable` which has its own `StackTraceElement[]`